# Better way to do calculations for multiple dataframes and return statement?

Tags: python, pandas

- My function looks through 3 dataframes, filters between different dates, and creates a statement.
- As you can see, the function is reusing the same steps over and over, and I would like to reduce them.
- I believe using a `for-loop` would help, but I'm unsure of how the `return` statement will be made in one small paragraph like I have now.

```
def stat_generator(df,date1,date2,df2,date3,date4,df4,date5,date6): 
    ##First Date Filter for First Dataframe, and calculations for first dataframe
    
    df['Announcement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Announcement Date'])
    mask = ((df['Announcement Date'] >= date1) & (df['Announcement Date'] <= date2))
    df_new = df.loc[mask]
    total = len(df_new)
    better = df_new[(df_new['performance'] == 'better')]
    better_perc = round(((len(better)/total)*100),2)
    worse = df_new[(df_new['performance'] == 'worse')]
    worse_perc = round(((len(worse)/total)*100),2)
    statement1 = "During the time period between {} and {}, {} % of the students performed better. {} % 
    of the students performed worse" .format(date1,date2,better_perc,worse_perc)
    
    ##Second Date Filter for Second Dataframe, and calculations for second dataframe
    
    df2['Announcement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Announcement Date'])
    mask2 = ((df2['Announcement Date'] >= date3) & (df2['Announcement Date'] <= date4))
    df_new2 = df2.loc[mask2]
    total2 = len(df_new2)
    better2 = df_new2[(df_new2['performance'] == 'better')]
    better_perc2 = round(((len(better2)/total2)*100),2)
    worse2 = df_new2[(df_new2['performance'] == 'worse')]
    worse_perc2 = round(((len(worse2)/total2)*100),2)
    statement2 = "During the time period between {} and {}, {} % of the students performed better. {} % 
    of the students performed worse" .format(date3,date4,better_perc2,worse_perc2)
    
    ##Third Date Filter for Third Dataframe, and calculations for third dataframe
    
    df3['Announcement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Announcement Date'])
    mask3 = ((df3['Announcement Date'] >= date5) & (df3['Announcement Date'] <= date6))
    df_new3 = df3.loc[mask3]
    total3 = len(df_new3)
    better3 = df_new3[(df_new3['performance'] == 'better')]
    better_perc3 = round(((len(better3)/total3)*100),2)
    worse3 = df_new3[(df_new3['performance'] == 'worse')]
    worse_perc3 = round(((len(worse3)/total3)*100),2)
    statement3 = "During the time period between {} and {}, {} % of the students performed better. {} % 
    of the students performed worse" .format(date5,date6,better_perc3,worse_perc3)

    statement = statement1 + statement2 + statement3 
    return statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just pass 3 parameters to your function those being df, date1 and date2 and then call your function 3 times.

```
def stat_generator(df,date1,date2):
    "..."
    return statement
```

Then pass in your data as a list of lists or something similar. For example:

```
data = [[df,date1,date2],[df2,date3,date4],[df4,date5,date6]]

for lists in data:
    stat_generator(*lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Maintaining Present Form

- Change the `df` parameter in `stat_generator` to `df1`, so `df` can be used in the `for-loop`.
- Group the data for each dataframe together
- Create a `statements` list, to be returned
- `date1` and `date2` are changed to `d1` and `d2` in the loop
- Updated `statement1` to use a more easily readable [`f-string`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).
- I think these updates require the least amount of changes to your overall code.
- Optionally:

  - Change `mask` to `mask = df['Announcement Date'].between(d1, d2, inclusive=True)`

```py
def stat_generator(df1, date1 ,date2 ,df2 ,date3 ,date4 ,df4 ,date5 ,date6): 
    ##First Date Filter for First Dataframe, and calculations for first dataframe
    
    # create groups
    groups = [(df1, date1, date2), (df2, date3, date4), (df3, date5, date6)]
    
    # create a statements list for each statement
    statements = list()
    
    # iterate through each group
    for (df, d1, d2) in groups:
    
        df['Announcement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Announcement Date'])
        mask = ((df['Announcement Date'] >= d1) & (df['Announcement Date'] <= d2))
        df_new = df.loc[mask]
        total = len(df_new)
        better = df_new[(df_new['performance'] == 'better')]
        better_perc = round(((len(better)/total)*100),2)
        worse = df_new[(df_new['performance'] == 'worse')]
        worse_perc = round(((len(worse)/total)*100),2)
        statement1 = f"During the time period between {d1} and {d2}, {better_perc}% of the students performed better. {worse_perc}%  of the students performed worse"
        
        # append the statement of the dataframe
        statements.append(statement1)

    # return a list of all the statements    
    return statements
```

### Complete Rewrite

- It's better for the function to do 1 thing, which is extract and return the data.
- Take care of passing multiple dataframes to the function, outside the function, and collect the results in a `list` or `print` them.
- It's not efficient to create a new dataframe for `better` and `worse`.

  - Use [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` to get the percentage.

```py
def stat_generator(df: pd.DataFrame, d1: str, d2: str) -> str: 
           
    df['Announcement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Announcement Date'])

    # create the mask
    mask = df['Announcement Date'].between(d1, d2, inclusive=True)

    # apply the mask
    df_new = df.loc[mask]

    # calculate the percentage
    per = (df_new.performance.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).round(2)

    return f"During the time period between {d1} and {d2}, {per['better']}% of the students performed better. {per['worse']}%  of the students performed worse"


groups = [(df1, date1, date2), (df2, date3, date4), (df3, date5, date6)]

statements = list()
for group in groups:
    statements.append(stat_generator(*group))
```